# Using perform selector function of NSObjectProtocol crash in Swift 3

Tags: swift, nsobject

I called perform selector function of NSObjectProtocol and try to get return value, crash why? Does anyone can help me. thx.

```
class Convert: NSObject {

     func value(_ value: CGFloat, from srcUnit: DWUnitType, to dstUnit: DWUnitType) {
        let selector = Selector("_centimeterToMillimeter:")
        let newValue = perform(selector, with: value).takeUnretainedValue() as? CGFloat
        print(newValue)
    }

     func _centimeterToMillimeter(_ value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return value * 10.0
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `perform(selector` rather than calling the method directly and why is the return value casted to an optional while the method actually returns a non-optional CGFloat??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether the bridging of CGFloat to Objective-C will work (possibly this is why you are crashing). Try this

```
 func _centimeterToMillimeter(_ value: Any) -> Any {
    return (value as! CGFloat) * 10.0
}
```

instead for your conversion function (or something to this effect). Just as a general comment, using the runtime (e.g. `perform:_:with`) your are abandoning the comfort of compile time checks and stepping into a world of hard to debug crashes. Better know what you are doing.